# Suggested Actions not visible in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'll send a pro-active message from a bot to Microsoft Teams with 2 suggested actions that the user can take. But in Microsoft Teams the message is shown like this:

[image]

Notice that the message shows no suggested messages! At the Bot Framework Emulator, the same message looks like this:

[image]

What's wrong in Teams or my code?

Below is my code to authenticate, generate and send the message:

```cs
private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string serviceUrl = turnContext.Activity.RelatesTo.ServiceUrl;

    ConnectorClient Connector = new ConnectorClient(
        new Uri(serviceUrl),
        microsoftAppId: "[MicrosoftAppId]",
        microsoftAppPassword: "[MicrosoftAppPassword]"
    );

    AppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
    ChannelAccount from = turnContext.Activity.From;
    IMessageActivity activity = MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(
        new string[] { "First action", "Second action" },
        $"Hi {userName},\r\nYou've missed some lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:\r\n- **consectetur:** Ut porttitor\r\nChoose an action from below to add them."
    );

    await Connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(
        turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, 
        activity as Activity, 
        cancellationToken
    );
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suggested actions are not supported in Teams. If you want to display buttons, you could use [Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions) in Teams.

Comment: Now I send this code https://pastebin.com/ji85Tt9L but when I select a action in Teams, it will send a null string to the bot so that he can't understand what the user means.

Comment: Can you give an example of a card that would be equivalent to Suggested actions? (i.e. it would disappear after the user pressed a button, send the value back to the bot, and display it in the chat window)

Answer (score 2):

Echoing the other response, but perhaps a bit more detail. As explained, the way to do this in Teams (and other clients) is to use "[Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-cards)" - kind of like mini windows inside the chat.  Teams supports a few different kinds of cards to suit different interactions, but the most prominent are called [Adaptive Cards](https://adaptivecards.io/). You can play more with these at the designer [here](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) and there's even a "designer" experience built into App Studio (where you can even have App Studio's bot "send" you the card to see what it looks like in a "real" conversation.

Comment: This should be a comment to the proposed solution, not an answer.

Comment: @StevenKanberg this answer is a lot more details then the other response

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn, you are right. But, it's not a new answer. It's adding details to an already provided solution. Ultimately, the solution is the same: "Echoing the other response", as he states.

Comment: Now I send this code https://pastebin.com/ji85Tt9L but when I select a action in Teams, it will send a null string to the bot so that he can't understand what the user means.

Comment: So it sounds like the card itself is rendering ok? What does your "CreateCardAction" method look like?