# Teams wil return a null string after a card action is selected

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'll send an adaptive card to the user with 2 actions, but when I select an action, a null string will be send to the server. Because of that the bot can't understand what the user wants.

As an extra check, I echo everything that the user sends to the bot. There is a null or empty check.

Here you've the conversation in Teams:

[image]

Here is the conversation in the emulator:

[image]

Here is my code to create the activity:

```cs
Activity activity = new Activity()
{
    Attachments = new List<Attachment>()
    {
        new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = new AdaptiveCard("1.0")
            {
                Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                {
                    new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                    {
                        Text = $"Lorem reminder",
                        Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large
                    },
                    new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                    {
                        Text = $"Hi {userName},\r\nYou've missed some lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:\r\n- **consectetur:** Ut porttitor\r\nChoose an action from below to add them."
                   }
               },
               Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
               {
                   CreateCardAction("First action"),
                   CreateCardAction("Second action")
               }
           }
       }
   },
   From = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
   Recipient = turnContext.Activity.From,
   Type = "message",
   Conversation = turnContext.Activity.Conversation
};
```

```cs
private AdaptiveAction CreateCardAction(string text)
{
    return new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
    {
        Title = text,
        Data = text
    };
}
```

Using type `imBack` for the `AdaptiveSubmitAction` *(like the [suggested actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863455/suggested-actions-not-visible-in-microsoft-teams))* don't work here. See screenshot from the emulator below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this locally, using NGrok, it's worth having a look at the payload in the ngrok inspector so that you see what's send back (http://localhost:4040/).

Essentially, "Data" is just an "object" type so that you can submit whatever you want on there. Let's say, for instance, that you want it to send back an "id" value - simple attach that as the "Data" property, like:

```
private AdaptiveAction CreateCardAction(string text, string id)
{
    return new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
    {
        Title = text,
        Data = id
    };
}
```

Alternatively, it can be a more complex object, like:

```
public class Foo {
   public string something { get; set; }
   public string id{ get; set; }
}

    private AdaptiveAction CreateCardAction(string text, Foo foo)
    {
        return new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
        {
            Title = text,
            Data = foo
        };
    }
```

then when the message comes in, on your OnTurnAsync, you can check if the Turncontext.Activity.Value contains something.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems that **Teams strips away plain string "Data" property** (which works perfectly fine on DirectLine channel instead).
If you are able to replace the plain string by a JObject, the problem is solved. 
 
*If - for any reason - you want your bot to act as a "bridge" and forward to Teams channel an AdaptiveCard with a plain string "Data" property coming from a different channel (i.e. DirectLine), than wrapping the "Data" string content in a JObject could save your day.*